# Core Animation scaling bizarrely slow?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, scaling, performance

As part of an iPhone game, I've got buttons that grow a little when you press them, and shrink back when you release (as a way of responding to user input).  The code responsible looks like this:

```
-(void) magnifyButton: (CALayer *) button
{
 button.transform = CATransform3DScale(button.transform, buttonPressScale, buttonPressScale, 1.0);
}

-(void) reduceButton: (CALayer *) button
{
 button.transform = CATransform3DScale(button.transform, 1.0 / buttonPressScale, 1.0 / buttonPressScale, 1.0);
}
```

This works great.  But if I press a button (each of which is a small image on a CALayer) repeatedly, the animations going on in the background (in an OpenGL view) slow to 10 FPS.  This seems absurd to me.  I've found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842042/iphone-scaling-images-are-very-slow-help), but since I'm using implicit animations I'm not sure how I would go about optimizing in this case.

If anybody can offer a suggestion on how to make this run at a more reasonable speed, I'd be much obliged.  Thanks in advance for you

Answer (score 2):

Before an animation begins, to save from having to render the `CALayer` for each frame, replace it with an image of itself:

```
button.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

When the animation is finished, set the property back to `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing UIKit and OpenGL is possible but will hurt performance. Things to avoid when combining the two are transparency and transformations. There's probably not a simple way to optimize this, best is ofcourse to do the buttons in OpenGL too.

Gamesfromwithin.com has a few good articles on combining UIKit and OpenGL. This article contains a section on performance (no solution though):
http://gamesfromwithin.com/using-multiple-opengl-views-and-uikit

Also check out his presentation on combining the two:
http://gamesfromwithin.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/GDC10_uikit_opengl.pdf