# Application becomes slow while changing brightness of image

Tags: iphone

To set brightness of an UIImage I am using

```
CGFloat brightness = 2.0;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.Input_Image.size);
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.Input_Image.size.width, self.Input_Image.size.height);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Original image
[self.Input_Image drawInRect:imageRect]; 

// Brightness overlay
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:brightness].CGColor);
CGContextAddRect(context, imageRect);
CGContextFillPath(context);

UIImage* resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But application becomes slow for big images...
Anyone can help me?? Thanks in advance ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842042/iphone-scaling-images-are-very-slow-help?rq=1

Comment: Its not working ... :(

Comment: I tried ios-image-filters-master also but same thing with it  :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use instruments to see where the performance is lagging. Which function is responsible for it. Try using Instruments.

Comment: In case of ios-image-filters-master CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage)); takes more time.  inImage is CGImageRef